# What does the great common divisor mean for this proof?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

**Theorem 1:  $\sqrt {2}\notin \mathbb{Q}$** .

Proof.

Suppose for a contradiction that $\sqrt {2}\in \mathbb{Q}$. So we have $Q = p/ q \ $ for $p\in \mathbb N$ and $q\in \mathbb N^{\ast}$.

with $\mathrm{gcd}(p, q) = 1$, because we can always represent a fraction so that the numerator and the denominator share no common factor.

Now, $$p/q=\sqrt {2}=p^{2}/q^{2}=2\Rightarrow p^{2}=2q^{2}$$
and $p^2$ is an even number. We have then that p is also even, by well known theroem (We take it for granted here). Let $k \in N$ be such that $p = 2k$.

Because $p^{2}=2q^{2}$ and $p = 2k$, we have $\left( 2k\right) ^{2}=2q^{2}\Rightarrow 4k^{2}=2q^{2}\Rightarrow 2k^{2}=q^{2}$  and $q^2$ is even. We now have that $q$ is even, by the same theorem we take for granted here. As a consequence, $\gcd(p, q) \geq 2$ and $p, q$ are not relatively prime, for a contradiction. ■

I am not sure I understand where the proof is getting at. My intuition is that because the gcd is not = 1 therefore we can't have a rational number. Can someone explain what the gcd (great common divisor) means for the proof?

Comment: Any rational number can written in the form $\frac{p}{q}$ where $p\in\mathbb{Z},q\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\gcd(p,q)=1$. So we assume $\sqrt{2}$ is rational and write it in that form. But then we get that it implies that both $p$ and $q$ are divisible by $2$. This is a contradiction to their $\gcd$ being $1$.

Comment: It means $\frac pq$ is in "lowest terms"  So if $p$ is even then $q$ can not be (and vice versa).  If $\frac {p^2}{q^2}= 2$ then $p^2 = 2q^2$ and so $p$ is even.  So $p = 2p'$ and $4p'^2 = 2q^2$ and so $2p'^2 = q^2$.  So $q$ is also even.  But that's impossible if $\frac pq$ were in lowest terms.  So it is impossible to have $(\frac pq)^2 = 2$ for any fraction in lowest terms. But *all* rationals can be put in lowest terms.  So $q^2 = 2$ is impossible if $q$ is rational.

Comment: "My intuition is that because the gcd is not = 1 therefore we can't have a rational number."  You *can*, but if $\gcd(p,q)\ne 1$ then $\frac pq$ is not in "lowest terms".  So we have $p=k\gcd(p,q)$ and $q=j\gcd(p,q)$ and we should use $\frac pq=\frac kj$ instead.  *NOW* we have a rational in lowest terms.  And yet... if $(\frac kj)^2=2$ we can prove they *aren't* in lowest terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now, $$p/q=\sqrt {2}=p^{2}/q^{2}=2\Rightarrow p^{2}=2q^{2}$$

The second equality sign should be implies

$$\frac pq=\sqrt {2}\implies \frac{p^2}{q^2}=2 \implies p^{2}=2q^{2}$$

> My intuition is that because the gcd is not $= 1$ therefore we can't have a rational number. Can someone explain what the gcd (great common divisor) means for the proof?

As the start of the proof you assume that $\sqrt {2}\in \mathbb{Q}$. This means that there exists $p\in\mathbb Z,q\in\mathbb N$ such that 
$$\sqrt{2}=\frac p q$$
where $\frac pq$ is in the lowest possible terms and $q\neq 0$. Now, what does lowest possible terms mean? Consider the rational number

$$\frac{36}{10}$$
this rational number is not in lowest possible terms as it can be rewritten as

$$\frac{36}{10}=\frac{18}{5}$$

therefore, by our assumption that $\frac p q$ is in lowest possible terms we also satisfy the condition that

$$\text{gcd(p,q)}=1$$

since if this wasn't true we would reduce $\sqrt{2}=\frac{p}{q}$ down to a $\tilde{p}\in\mathbb Z,\tilde{q}\in\mathbb N$ such that $${\text gcd(\tilde{p},\tilde{q})}=1$$

> Because $p^{2}=2q^{2}$ and $p = 2k$, we have $\left( 2k\right) ^{2}=2q^{2}\Rightarrow 4k^{2}=2q^{2}\Rightarrow 2k^{2}=q^{2}$  and $q^2$ is even. We now have that $q$ is even, by the same theorem we take for granted here. As a consequence, $gcd(p, q) \geq 2$ and $p, q$ are not relatively prime, for a contradiction.

Your proof shows that both $p$ and $q$ are even and therefore the greatest common divisor between them is greater than or equal to 2.

$$\text{gcd(p,q)}\ge 2$$

By definition, if $p$ is even then

$$p=2k,~~k\in\mathbb Z$$

and if $q$ is even then

$$q=2m,~~m\in\mathbb Z$$
so that

$$\text{gcd(p,q)}=\text{gcd(2k,2m)}\ge2>1$$
which is a direct contradiction to the initial assumption that
$$\text{gcd(p,q)}=1$$

Answer (score 2):

The idea behind the proof is that you assume that $gcd(p,q) = 1$ and that leads to a contradiction since you show that the $gcd(p,q) \geq 2$.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that if $\gcd(p,q) = d\ne 1$ then we will have $p=kd$ and $q = jd$ for some $k,j$.  And so $\frac {p}{q} = \frac {kd}{jd} = \frac kj$ and $\frac pq$ was not in "lowest terms".

So we might as well assume that $\gcd(p,q) =1$ and that $\frac pq$ is lowest term.

The assumption is every rational $q$ can be expressed as $\frac {p}{q}$ where $p$ and $q$ are in lowest terms.  The text is taking that for granted.[1]

So if $m^2 =2$ and $m =\frac pq$ and $p,q$ are integers *AND* $\frac pq$ is in lowest terms then........

$\frac {p^2}{q^2} =2$

$p^2 = 2q^2$

$2|p^2$ and so $2|p$ so there is a $k$ so that $p = 2k$ so

$4k^2 =2q^2$

$2k^2 =q^2$

$2|q^2$ and so $2|q$.  So $2|p$ and $2|q$ so..... $\frac pq$ wasn't in lowest terms.

So we either have a rational that can never be expressed in lowest terms [1], or there's some other type of "irrational" number that $m$ could be, or there's no possible number so that $m^2 = 2$[2].

....

[1] We can prove it.  If $r$ is rational there are two integers,$p,q$ so that $r = \frac {p}{q}$ if $\gcd(p,q)=d\ne 1$ then $p=kd$ and $q=jd$ for some $k,j$ and $m = \frac pq =\frac kj$.  And $\gcd(k,j)$ *DOES* equal $1$.

Why.  Because $\gcd(k,j)|k$ and $\gcd(k,j)|j$ so $d*\gcd(k,j)$ divides $p$ and divides $q$.  So $d*\gcd(k,j) \ge \gcd(k,j)$ and a common divisor.  But $d$ was the *greatest* common divisor.  So $\gcd(k,j) =1$.

And $m =\frac kj$ and is in  "lowest terms".

[2]  But if we take square of side $1$.  That's got to be possible.  And we take its diagonal.  That's got to be possible.  ANd we call the length of the diagonal $m$. The diagonal has to have *some* length. And we use the Pythagorian Theorem.  That P.T. is true, isn't it.  Then $1^2 + 1^2 = m^2$ or in other words: $m^2 =2$.

Hmmmm.